# Firebase Cloud Function Emulator Not Starting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to test my cloud functions locally using the cloud function emulator but it doesnt seem to work. What happens it when i run:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

I get the following:

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
+  hub: emulator hub started at http://localhost:4400
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

Having trouble? Try again or contact support with contents of firebase-debug.log
```

This is how my firebase.json looks like:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {}
}
```

I've tried running, `firebase init` several times, and also `firebase init emulators` but none of them have worked so far.

The account am signed in with has Editor permission on it.
Please help I seriously need this.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this too, but creating a build fixed the issue for me, e.g `npm run build` or `yarn build`

This recreates `node_modules` and possibly updates your lock file to sync dependencies

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried running, firebase init several times, and also firebase init emulators but none of them have worked so far.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure .

```
You will need CLI version 7.8.0 or higher to use the Emulator Sute.
```

At first, could you check your node version and firebase version?

The following log is command history log at my local machine.

```
$ node -v
v10.20.1
$ firebase -V
8.2.0
$ firebase emulators:start
i  emulators: Starting emulators: firestore
i  firestore: downloading cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.3.jar...
Progress: ====================================================================================================> (100% of 64MB
i  firestore: Removing outdated emulator files: cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.10.2.jar
i  firestore: firestore emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
✔  firestore: firestore emulator started at http://localhost:8080
i  firestore: For testing set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080
✔  emulators: All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

.firebaserc

```
{}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    }
  }
}
```